# KDE Plasma 5 Text Box Border Highlight Not In Correct Position

Tags: kubuntu, kde, home-directory, plasma, plasma-5

I recently added Manjaro to my setup that already had Kubuntu 21.04 and Windows 10. Kubuntu and Manjaro are sharing the /home partition, so I'm using the same user account on both systems. Everything is fine until I log into Kubuntu, and noticed that the border around textboxes in places like the lock screen (not the logon screen) and the search box in the application menu look very strange. This takes place only in the Breeze and Breeze Dark Plasma styles, which makes sense, but I'm not sure how to fix this.
[image: Image of the broken color border on the application menu]

Comment: Are the two using exactly the same version of  Qt5, KF5 & programs... Yes I've done what you are doing and not had issues, however if they get out of sync, you can run into problems now or in the future & they were enough for me at least, to decide it was a bad approach (I share some common files; but the homework in reading about each update & changes made just wasn't worth it to avoid problems on each update).

Comment: @guiverc I decided to remove Manjaro, but the problem still exits, is there a way to reset these settings to fix it?